# What is "compatibility for C++ mangling"?

Tags: c++, c, compatibility, glibc, abi

`wint_t` type is set inside `wchar.h` via `stddef.h`, using the fact that `__WINT_TYPE__` is already defined in the compiler by default. So to change

```
typedef unsigned int wint_t;
```

into

```
typedef wchar_t wint_t;
```

we may use the following code in the beginning of `wchar.h`

```
#undef __WINT_TYPE__
#define __WINT_TYPE__ wchar_t
#define WEOF (-1)
```

But [this](https://sourceware.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=20639#c4) comment suggests that doing this "breaks compatibility for C++ mangling".

> You can't change existing definitions of typedefs such as wint_t without breaking ABI compatibility (even when you have the same size and 
>   signedness and so are ABI-compatible for C, changing the underlying type 
>   breaks compatibility for C++ mangling).

So, why exactly this typedef cannot be changed and what is "compatibility for C++ mangling"?

See also this question [How to change wchar.h to make wchar_t the same type as wint_t?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40601645/)

Comment: In C++, `wchar_t` is a separated type

Comment: That said, functions with C linkage don't include types in the mangling, so I'm not entirely sure how such a change could affect anything C++ related. See also [diff.wchar.t]; no such typedef would be exposed to C++.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

So here's some relevant definitions:

- ABI: [Application Binary Interface](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Application_binary_interface)
- [Name Mangling](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Name_mangling#Real-world_effects_of_C.2B.2B_name_mangling)

Name mangling is the way that the compile represents the method-names you define in C++ so that they're qualified "per class" so for instance `ClassA::method()` doesn't clash with `ClassB::method()` - this also facilitates overloading such that `ClassA::method(String s)` doesn't clash with `ClassA::method(int i)`.

Internally these might be represented something like `ClassA_method`, `ClassA_method^String`, `ClassA_method^int`

As the second topic above discusses *"name mangling is not merely a compiler-internal matter"* - in cases where a public interface for a shared library is being generated, for instance.

So if you take a typedef and change it for your own code, it'll be okay for all the binaries you generate, but any pre-existing binaries such as 3rd party DLLs that depend on this typedef will break.

Answer (score 3):

Another case where mixing C and C++ hurts you. The question only makes sense in the non-existent "C/C++" language.

In C, name mangling is rare, and for standard ABI's does not include type names. Hence, it doesn't matter what `wchar_t`'s real name is.

In C++, `wchar_t` is not a typedef.

Answer (score 2):

I assume you know what mangling is. If not a good explanation is [here](http://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/ssw_ibm_i_73/rzarg/name_mangling.htm).

I also assume that by compatibility it means that it has to do with various compilers. I know that certain ARM compilers such as Keil handle certain things differently than standard GCC and Clang on desktop/server when it comes to name mangling.

That would be normally also documented like [this](http://www.keil.com/support/man/docs/armmigration/armmigration_Chunk1329315602.htm).

By changing a certain type on your own, you can break a compiler default mapping for name mangling on a certain system.