# How to cast to `wint_t` and to `wchar_t`?

Tags: c, standards, wchar-t, widechar, c-standard-library

Are the standards saying that casting to `wint_t` and to `wchar_t` in the following two programs is guaranteed to be correct?

```
#include <locale.h>
#include <wchar.h>
int main(void)
{
  setlocale(LC_CTYPE, "");
  wint_t wc;
  wc = getwchar();
  putwchar((wchar_t) wc);
}
```

--

```
#include <locale.h>
#include <wchar.h>
#include <wctype.h>
int main(void)
{
  setlocale(LC_CTYPE, "");
  wchar_t wc;
  wc = L'ÿ';
  if (iswlower((wint_t) wc)) return 0;
  return 1;
}
```

Consider the case where `wchar_t` is `signed short` (this
hypothetical implementation is limited to the BMP), `wint_t` is `signed int`, and `WEOF == ((wint_t)-1)`.  Then `(wint_t)U+FFFF` is
indistinguishable from `WEOF`.  Yes, `U+FFFF` is a reserved codepoint, but
it's still wrong for it to collide.

I would not want to swear that this never happens in real life without
an exhaustive audit of existing implementations.

See also [May wchar_t be promoted to wint_t?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40757681/may-wchar-t-be-promoted-to-wint-t)

Comment: There is no standard that mentions wint_t.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On the environment you describe, `wchar_t` cannot accurately describe the BMP: `L'\uFEFF'` exceeds the range of `wchar_t` as its type is the **unsigned** equivalent to `wchar_t`. (C11 **6.4.4.4 Character constants p9**). Storing it to `wchar_t` defined as `signed short`, assuming 16-bit shorts, changes its value.

On the other hand, if the charset used for the source code is Unicode and the compiler is properly configured to parse its encoding correctly, `L'ÿ'` has the value `255` with an unsigned type, so the code in the second example is perfectly defined and unambiguous.

If `int` is 32-bit wide and `short` 16-bit wide, it seems much more consistent to define `wchar_t` as either `int` or `unsigned short`.  `WEOF` can then be defined as `(-1)`, a value different from all values of `wchar_t` or at least all values representing Unicode code-points.

Comment: But returning `(-1)` to an `unsigned short` is equivalent to 0xFFFF which would be a valid character in unicode, or am I forgetting something?

Comment: You seem to have confused UTf-8 and codepoint in your middle paragraph, in UTF-8 the octet 255 is not valid, and `L'ÿ'` in UTF-8 is encoded as two octets, C3 BF.

Comment: @PeteKirkham: I rephrased the answer for clarity, the charset and the file encoding are 2 different matters, we are not concerned about the encoding, as long as it is correct and properly configured.

Comment: @KamiKaze: `0xFFFF` is actually an invalid Unicode code-point, but if `wchar_t` is unsigned, it would be a valid `wchar_t` value, and it would make sense that it be different from `WEOF`, which can be achieved by defining `WEOF` as `(-1)` and `wint_t` as `int`.