# How to wrap glibc library functions to automatically use 'unsigned char' and 'wchar_t'?

Tags: c, glibc

I always use `char` as `unsigned char` and `wchar_t` as `wint_t`. Given that, does there exist a solution to change function interfaces to use those types with or without recompiling glibc? See also this question: [How to change wchar.h to make wchar_t the same type as wint_t?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40601645/how-to-change-wchar-h-to-make-wchar-t-the-same-type-as-wint-t)

Comment: Don't. :) You're asking for problems. Good question though.

Comment: When I said 'wrap' I meant to write a new wrapper function such as `ToUpper()` that calls through to `toupper()`, and change your code to call the wrapper. Then you can add your own code inside the wrapper to fix just about anything. It's a good general policy.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can pass a command line option to the compiler to make `char` unsigned by default. Changing the interface to standard library functions by redefining `char` with macros and typedefs is not the correct way to achieve your goal.

For gcc and clang, use `-funsigned-char`.

For Visual-C++, use `-J` or `/J`.

The wide character type `wchar_t` is system specific, it typically 32-bit wide on linux systems and wherever the glibc is used, but only 16-bit wide for the Microsoft tools for historical reasons.  Changing this type will cause compatibility problems between the compiler and the libraries, don't even think about it.

Comment: How to make char unsigned by default without using `-funsigned-char` gcc option? I don't want to type each time, or create aliases and stuff. I just want to use the command `gcc` and have this behavior by default. Maybe there is a config file or a pragma to be put directly into a program?

Comment: Why argument type of `putchar()`, `fputc()` and `putc()` is not `char`, but argument type of `putwchar()`, `fputwc()` and `putwc()` is `wchar_t`? Also, why in example from man `mbstowcs` the variable of type `wchar_t` is passed to `iswlower()` ? This contradicts to the fact that `iswlower()` takes `wint_t`. Is the example wrong?

Comment: @IgorLiferenko: That one is worth another question on its own.